# What index types in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast to save map Object Class which has many properties with difference types

Example

```
  public class Person() {
      public int id;
      public Syting name;
      public Date birthDay;
      public boolean isVip;
  }
```

So, how i can put map with object data and hazelconfig.xml as

```
  <indexes>
            <index ordered="true">id</index>
            <index ordered="true">name</index>
            <index ordered="false">birthDay</index>
            <index ordered="false">isVip</index>
  </indexes>
```

Thank you very much for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add your person to a map with the configured indexes.

```
Map personMap = hz.getMap("persons"):
personMap.put("1", new Person(.......))
```

Hazelcast will inspect the object and check if there are any fields/methods which match with the index definitions.

PS:
Why would you need ordered index on name of id? Unordered index is faster AFAIK.